# Block the access of specific! USB devices

Tags: windows-10, internet, usb-flash-drive, ip-camera

I have some plugged USB devices in the computer, and I worry they might be used to "spy" - access the internet\ransomware.
For example, a USB camera or a USB stick that will be connected to the computer.

How do I **prevent** (new or specific existing) USB devices from sending data to the internet or reading/writing to the hard drive?

Comment: What kind of USB devices? How would they access the internet? Why is spying on you so important to somebody?

Comment: @BestR - are you ok with disabling ALL USB devices, or only certain ones that are connected?

Comment: @harrymc your questions about 'what kind of device' and 'How would they access the net' are valid, however there are plenty of good reasons people may have to be spied on, and its none of our business asking people this kind of question. –

Comment: @KalamalkaKid: A spying device tricked out as a banal USB device with its own network adapter and with enough power to punch through walls without being detected is not cheap, and if it exists then it is the domain of specialized security services like the FBI. Any such organization does not need to plant tricked devices in order to spy. So the question is if he thinks such an organization is interested in him, because since the answer is (most likely) "No" then he has nothing to fear.

Comment: @harrymc
I said what kind of devices. For example, a camera that is connected to the computer and has a software in it. Or a USB drive that has a ransomware in it which is activated on connection

Comment: @KalamalkaKid I dont want to disable all USB devices..since keyboard and mouse are USB. Also, I want to use the camera, just dont let it access the the internet.
I want the option to block them using the firewall somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All devices inside your computer have software/firmware, such the hard disk,
the network adapter, the display adapter, the BIOS/UEFI and more.
There's nothing special about USB and no way to protect against infected hardware,
since you do need to use these devices from time to time.

However, the firmware of devices is usually protected by digital signature,
just as UEFI (in non-Legacy mode) protects in the same way against infected
operating system components, so that they cannot be maliciously modified.

Spying software can in almost all cases only be incorporated into the device
by the manufacturer of the device and/or the firmware. The best protection
would be by not buying hardware from dubious sources.

Windows has also much advanced regarding protection, and the days when an
external hard disk could infect the computer are long gone. Windows will not
launch software from such disks, unless done explicitly by yourself.

I think that you have nothing to worry about, as long as you keep Windows, the router
and the anti-virus completely up-to-date, and do not open holes in the
firewall of Windows and your router. Windows does a very good job nowadays
of keeping you safe, much better than any measure that you can do yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, I suspect the firmware. If there is no way I block the specific camera from accessing the internet, Is there a way to check if the firmware is legit?

Comment: The camera can only access the internet via your router and wifi (unless it is cabled to the router). If the router is set to whitelist only known devices by their MAC then you are safe (this is also a good idea in order to keep your neighbors away).

Comment: Im talking about a USB camera that is connected to the computer, or a USB stick that will actiavte a program.

Comment: This is Windows 10, not Windows 7? No USB can launch a program automatically, only you can, and Windows Defender is now very good.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you are going to prevent individual devices from connecting to the computer other than being physically present when users are using the machine, but there are some settings you can use for the camera in Windows 10.

> ## Windows 10 privacy settings
>
> Windows 10 offers greater control than previous versions over the
> devices connected to computers and it presents these options in a very
> simple and intuitive interface. To access them just open the Start
> menu and select Settings. Click on the Privacy section and head over
> to Camera options in the left pane

[image]

> Here you’ll find a list of applications that have access to your
> webcam alongside controls to enable or disable said access. At the top
> of the window you also have a master switch that disables access to
> the camera for all applications listed.
>
> Please note that not all installed applications are listed here. For
> example I have Skype and Yahoo! Messenger installed, applications with
> camera access, and they are not listed here. The applications found
> here are mostly the ones installed from the Windows Store, so please
> keep this in mind when reviewing your privacy settings.

[Source](https://windowsreport.com/block-webcam-usage-windows-10/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You did not understand my question. I suspect the camera itself. I dont want to let it use the computer internet and broadcast/send data. This options block apps from accesing the camera, and I want the reverse options - stop the camera from using the computer resources.

Comment: You suspect the camera is what?

Comment: For example sending data to the internet to the C&C / launching ransoware to the computer

Comment: cameras cant do this.

Comment: https://www.pcmag.com/news/invisible-malware-is-here-and-your-security-software-cant-catch-it

Comment: The camera can not install root kits on its own.